# Odoo 10 - Extend a Javascript of point of sale Module

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, point-of-sale

i want to override a **ReceiptScreen** method from *point_of_sale* module.

```
var ReceiptScreenWidget = ScreenWidget.extend...

gui.define_screen({name:'receipt', widget: ReceiptScreenWidget});
```

In order to do this, i've created my own module but i don't know what steps follow to change the *ReceiptScreenWidget.print()* function.

Here is the [screens.js](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/js/screens.js) that contains the Widget.Function that i want to override. (search for: ReceiptScreenWidget)

I tried to follow this [example](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/how-can-i-extend-a-js-web-module-64) but the code is from Odoo 8 or 9 so i couldn't make it work.

*Odoo version: 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**JS**

```
odoo.define('your_module_name.filename', function (require) {
"use strict";

var gui = require('point_of_sale.gui');
var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');
var core = require('web.core');
var QWeb = core.qweb;
var _t = core._t;

screens.ReceiptScreenWidget.include({
    print: function() {
    // Your code
    },
});

});
```

**XML to add JS**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
        <template id="assets" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
          <xpath expr="." position="inside">
              <script type="text/javascript" src="/your_module_name/static/js/filename.js"></script>
          </xpath>
        </template>
</odoo>
```

**Add that xml in __manifest__.py**

```
{
...
...
'data': [
        ...
        'views/above_xml_filename.xml',
    ],
....
}
```